# Compare two Objects and replace the common object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays as below and i would like to find the common properties between the objects and replace properties from Object 1 into Object 2

```
Object 1: noAssignmentArray
[{
  AWART: "awart",
  LGART: "lgart",
  LTXA1: "ltxa1"
}]

Object 2: 
[{
  AllowEdit: ""
  AllowRelease: "X"
  ApproverId: "00000000" 
  TimeEntryDataFields:{
    ALLDF: ""
    APNAM: ""
    ARBID: "10004821"
    ARBPL: ""
    AUERU: ""
    AWART: "state",
    LGART: "material",
    LTXA1: "value"
  }
}]
```

Expected Result in Object 2

```
[{
  AllowEdit: ""
  AllowRelease: "X"
  ApproverId: "00000000" 
  TimeEntryDataFields:{
    ALLDF: ""
    APNAM: ""
    ARBID: "10004821"
    ARBPL: ""
    AUERU: ""
    **AWART: "awart",
    LGART: "lgart",
    LTXA1: "ltxa1"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Did you try to solve the problem yourself? If so, can you show us the code?

Comment: The object1 is not properly: Where is the key for `0:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this helps you, assuming that you really have arrays with exactly one element which contains the actual payload:

```
const assignment = assignmentArray[0];
const newDataFields = noAssignmentArray[0];
Object.assign(assignment.TimeEntryDataFields, newDataFields);
```

This makes use of the function [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which just copies all properties from the second argument object into the first argument object without checking whether this would result in any changes.

Comment: Can you please suggest to make it work for multiple elements in arrays

Comment: Totally depends on what you want to achieve. For example if the arrays have the same length and the objects with same indices shall be combined as above, then my just use a for-loop to iterate from 0 to < array length, get the two objects at that index and use the solution for the extracted objects. Probably you should ask more specific questions if you have problems understanding any of those concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ES6 spread operator for merging the first element of the obj2 array

```
Obj2[0] = {...Obj2[0], ...Obj1[0]}
```

General Syntax is

```
{...X, ...Y} // ES6
Object.assign({}, X, Y) // Before ES6
```